# How to make same height columns with same height inner elements? Bad solution proposed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

**Problem:** I want to make a responsive layout with 5 columns. Each column have an image, a title and a text. I want the images alienated with all other images, the titles alienated with the titles, and the text with the text. The heigh of the elements should be equal to the maximum height of the larger element of it's row.

**Solution found:** I achieved the result iterating over the different elements that I want to be the same heigh, checking the maximum height and setting all elements to this height with javascript. Then I added another script that does this precess over again every time that the window resizes. Here a [code pen demo](https://codepen.io/nsuria/pen/JjXoZOL) of what I have.

**What I look for:** I look for a best practice method for achieving this result. I guess it should be possible with plain css.

Thank you all!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Same height text
    var max = 0;
    $(".same-height").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).height() > max) {
            max = $(this).height()
        }
    });
    $(".same-height").height(max);

    //same heigh image
    var max2 = 0;
    $(".same-height-img").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).height() > max2) {
            max2 = $(this).height()
        }
    });
    $(".same-height-img").height(max2);

    //Execute the operation every time that the window resizes. 

    //Same height text
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        var max1 = 0; 
        //We need to set the height to auto first to get the initial value. 
        $(".same-height").css("height", "auto");
        $(".same-height").each(function (i){
            if($(this).height()>max1) {
                max1 = $(this).height()
            }
        });
        $(".same-height").height(max1);
        //Same height image
        var max2 = 0; 
        //We need to set the height to auto first to get the initial value. 
        $(".same-height-img").css("height", "auto");
        $(".same-height-img").each(function (i){
            if($(this).height()>max2) {
                max2 = $(this).height()
            }
        });
        $(".same-height-img").height(max2);
    } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PDle/QlgIONtM1aqA2Qemk5gPOE7wFq8+Em+G/hmo5Iq0CCmYZLv3fVRDJ4MMwEA" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="same-height-img"><img class="rounded mx-auto d-block " src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt=""></div>
      <h1 class="text-center same-height">The title</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Beatae, ad, eos nam fugiat labore quam quibusdam dignissimos. Largerrrrrrrr rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr rrrrrrrrrr
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="same-height-img"><img class="rounded mx-auto d-block " src="https://via.placeholder.com/350

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt=""></div>
      <h1 class="text-center same-height">The large large large title</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Beatae, ad, eos nam fugiat labore quam quibusdam dignissimos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="same-height-img"><img class="rounded mx-auto d-block " src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt=""></div>
      <h1 class="text-center same-height">The title</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Beatae, ad, eos nam fugiat labore quam quibusdam dignissimos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="same-height-img"><img class="rounded mx-auto d-block " src="https://via.placeholder.com/150

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt=""></div>

      <h1 class="text-center same-height">The title</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Beatae, ad, eos nam fugiat labore quam quibusdam dignissimos.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="same-height-img"><img class="rounded mx-auto d-block " src="https://via.placeholder.com/190

C/O https://placeholder.com/ " alt=""></div>
      <h1 class="text-center same-height">The title</h1>
      <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Beatae, ad, eos nam fugiat labore quam quibusdam dignissimos.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a set of equal width and height cards, you can use Bootstrap built-in [card decks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-decks). So instead of using the rows and columns, you can give the card decks a try:

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title text-center" />
                <p class="card-text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" />
        <div class="card" />
        <div class="card" />
        <div class="card" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you use `.card` to wrap your stuff, it should automatically get the images aligned.

And then you need to come up a strategy about what to do when the title overflows. The simple strategy I came up was just to display "..." when it overflows a single line. That way you're sure that the titles will be aligned because they will only take up a line.

There is a Bootstrap class for truncating the texts: `.text-truncate`:

```html
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" />
    <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title text-center text-truncate" />
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Those two changes should give you results like:

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/uv4zbomL/34/

I don't know if this is good enough, but at least it will give you something to start with.

#### Update: to display titles completely

To make the title display completely, instead of using text-overflow technique, you would have to make the `.card-body` displayed as a flex box in column direction so that you can set the card header's margin buttom to auto, which will push other stuff in the body to the bottom. You can use Bootstrap built-in classes for that: `d-flex flex-column` and `mb-auto`:

```html
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" />
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
        <h1 class="card-title text-center mb-auto" />
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/uv4zbomL/47/

Comment: Hi David! Thanks a lot for your answer. I've been playing with card class, but I didn't get the result I wont for the title alignment. Your solution comes close, but I need the title to display completely.

Comment: @NilSuria: Sorry I've been extremely busy at work. Please see my update.

Comment: this is what I wanted. Thank you a lot! :)